# How to identify page breaks in excel with VBA, varying conditions

Tags: excel, vba

This is a problem I've been wrestling with for some time.  Forgive me for not citing the exact threads I've researched, but I've not been keeping a log.  The code sample I have below has been constructed from reviewing many threads on this topic.  However, the exact solution I need still evades me.

Simply put: In Excel VBA, I need to be able to identify the last row and first/last column of each page in a long table which could be from 1 to 5 pages long (horizontally), after having been dynamically created and populated. I would also appreciate a quick way to identify where the populated data stops, but can get that from the generating routine if there's no easy solution. The following code will identify the correct final row and column of a single page table... once. I can make the modification needed to check subsequent pages for a multi-page table.  The real problem I'm having is that once a cell has been populated and cleared, excel includes that cell in the range of used cells.  Subsequent executions of this same code fail, because the last cell is no longer correctly identified.  Is there anyway to reverse this, or a different approach I could take?

I truly do not like populating cells and deleting them to find the page breaks, but I've not found a solution that avoids doing so.  Thanks for any guidance you might provide.   ,Mike Shanahan

```
Sub Findpagebreaks()

Dim x As HPageBreaks, pb_x As HPageBreak
Dim y As VPageBreaks, pb_y As VPageBreak, PageMatrix() As Integer
Dim LastPopulated(1) As Integer, test As Integer, target As Integer

ReDim PageMatrix(1 To 1, 0 To 2) As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print "============================================"

    Debug.Print "Horizontal Page Breaks"
    Set x = .HPageBreaks
    Debug.Print "Initial Hbreaks: ", x.Count
    LastPopulated(0) = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Debug.Print "Last row of data: ", LastPopulated(0)
    target = x.Count + 1
    test = LastPopulated(0)
    Do While x.Count < target
        test = test + 10
        .Cells(test, 1).Value = "."
        Debug.Print "cell: " & .Cells(test, 1).Address & " populated"
        If test > 100 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    For Each pb_x In x
        If pb_x.Extent = xlPageBreakFull Then
            Debug.Print "Row: " & pb_x.Location.Row, "Full Page Break"
            PageMatrix(1, 2) = pb_x.Location.Row - 1
        Else
            Debug.Print "Row: " & pb_x.Location.Row, "Partial Page Break"
        End If
    Next pb_x
    .Range(.Cells(LastPopulated(0) + 1, 1), .Cells(test, 1)).ClearContents
    Debug.Print "cells: " & .Range(.Cells(LastPopulated(0), 1), .Cells(test, 1)).Address & " cleared."
    Debug.Print "Horizontal Exploration complete."


    Debug.Print "Vertical Page Breaks"
    Set y = .VPageBreaks
    Debug.Print "Initial vbreaks: ", y.Count
    LastPopulated(1) = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Debug.Print "Last column of data: ", LastPopulated(1)
    target = y.Count + 1
    test = LastPopulated(1)
    Do While y.Count < target
        test = test + 10
        .Cells(1, test).Value = "."
        Debug.Print "cell: " & .Cells(1, test).Address & " populated"
        If test > 100 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    PageMatrix(1, 0) = 1
    For Each pb_y In y
        If pb_y.Extent = xlPageBreakFull Then
            Debug.Print "column: " & pb_y.Location.Column, "Full Page Break"
            PageMatrix(1, 1) = pb_y.Location.Column - 1
        Else
            Debug.Print "Row: " & pb_y.Location.Column, "Partial Page Break"
        End If
    Next pb_y
    .Range(.Cells(1, LastPopulated(1) + 1), .Cells(1, test)).ClearContents
        Debug.Print "cells: " & .Range(.Cells(1, LastPopulated(1)), .Cells(1, test)).Address & " cleared."
    Debug.Print "Vertical Exploration complete."


    Debug.Print "Page", "First Col", "Last Col", "Last Row"
    Debug.Print 1, PageMatrix(1, 0), PageMatrix(1, 1), PageMatrix(1, 2)
    Debug.Print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    Debug.Print "Sub complete."
    Debug.Print

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: xlCellTypeLastCell is not what you want to use. Take a look at the GetLastCell function [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastCell.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Yan F.  I'll look into that function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I've opted for a solution that reduces the coding and makes a more robust product.  It isn't the sophisticated answer I was looking for, still falls under brute force methodology, but it's definitely less burdensome.

This is the best I have for now.  IF someone finds a more elegant solution, feel free to post it!  Thanks all.

```
Sub Findpagebreaks()

Dim y As VPageBreaks, pb_y As VPageBreak, PageMatrix() As Integer
Dim LastPopulated(1) As Integer, roww As Integer, coll As Integer
Dim lastpage As Integer, LookingForLastPage As Boolean, last_row As Integer

ReDim PageMatrix(0 To 2, 1 To 1) As Integer
PageMatrix(0, 1) = 1   'First column of page 1, always = 1
LookingForLastPage = True
lastpage = 1

With ActiveSheet
    '  In practice, this sub will be passed values for row and coll
    '  which represent the anticipated row & col that are populated
    '  to span the used range.
    roww = 13
    coll = 1
    LastPopulated(0) = .Cells(.Rows.Count, coll).End(xlUp).Row
    LastPopulated(1) = .Cells(roww, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print "Last row of data: ", LastPopulated(0)
    Debug.Print "Last column of data: ", LastPopulated(1)
    .Cells(LastPopulated(0) + 50, LastPopulated(1) + 10).Value = "."
    last_row = .HPageBreaks(1).Location.Row - 1
    Set y = .VPageBreaks
    For Each pb_y In y
        If LookingForLastPage Then
            If lastpage > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve PageMatrix(0 To 2, 1 To lastpage) As Integer
                PageMatrix(0, lastpage) = PageMatrix(1, lastpage - 1) + 1
            End If
            PageMatrix(1, lastpage) = pb_y.Location.Column - 1
            PageMatrix(2, lastpage) = last_row
            If pb_y.Location.Column > LastPopulated(1) Then _
                LookingForLastPage = False Else: lastpage = lastpage + 1
        End If
    Next pb_y
    .Cells(LastPopulated(0) + 50, LastPopulated(1) + 10).ClearContents
    Debug.Print "Page", "First Col", "Last Col", "Last Row"
    For i = 1 To lastpage
        Debug.Print i, PageMatrix(0, i), PageMatrix(1, i), PageMatrix(2, i)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    Debug.Print "Last page is: ", lastpage

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer, but greatly reduces some code.

Sure seems like a lot of code just to find page breaks. For page breaks, try this simple routine. Modify for your situation.

```
Sub Sample()
  'Horizontal Pagebreaks
  For h = 1 To 100
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(h).PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then MsgBox "Hor " & n
  Next
  'Vertical Pagebreaks
  For v = 1 To 100
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(v).PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then MsgBox "Ver " & n
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mitch. Unfortunately, this only works for the pagebreaks that have been established. I need to be able to find the pagebreaks when the data hasn't crossed over yet, (i.e. .VPageBreaks.Count = 0). It's okay though, I'm throwing in the towel and opting for a simpler approach, if less sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub List_VPageBreaks()
Set f = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
For i = 1 To f.VPageBreaks.Count
 Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).value=f.VPageBreaks(i).Location.Column
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Docmarti.  Unfortunately, this only works for the pagebreaks that have been established.  I need to be able to find the pagebreaks when the data hasn't crossed over yet, (i.e.  .VPageBreaks.Count = 0). It's okay though, I'm throwing in the towel and opting for a simpler approach, if less sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the row in the risk zone? Use and modify this function

```
Function PageBreak(iRow As Integer) As Boolean
Dim wsBook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wsBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wsBook.ActiveSheet

Dim iCellHeight As Integer, i As Integer
Dim iSense As Integer, iBreak As Integer, iPage As Integer

'How sensitive +/- should the PageBreak be?
iSense = 32
'At what height does your printer brake? 'PageBreak 757 <> 758
iBreak = 758

'Sum of all pages
For i = 1 To iRow
    iCellHeight = iCellHeight + ws.Cells(i, 1).Height
Next i

'How many pages
iPage = iCellHeight \ (iBreak + iSense) + 1
'Get height from last page
iCellHeight = iCellHeight \ iPage

If (iCellHeight > iBreak - iSense And iCellHeight < iBreak + iSense) Then
    PageBreak = True
Else
    PageBreak = False
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I did one that just gives you the number of rows columns and pages, its a bit clunky but it works for my purposes

```
`Sub Test()

  Dim num_of_Rows As Integer
  Dim num_of_Columns As Integer
  Dim num_of_Pages As Integer
  
  num_of_Pages = -1
  num_of_Rows = 1
  num_of_Columns = 1
  
  'total number of pages vertical
  For p = 1 To 500
    If Sheets("Mat_20155").Rows(p).PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then num_of_Pages = num_of_Pages + 1
    Debug.Print num_of_Pages
  Next
  'Horizontal Pagebreaks
  For h = 2 To 100
    If Sheets("Mat_20155").Rows(h).PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone Then num_of_Rows = num_of_Rows + 1 Else: Exit For
    Debug.Print num_of_Rows
        
  Next
  'Vertical Pagebreaks
  For v = 2 To 100
    If Sheets("Mat_20155").Columns(v).PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone Then num_of_Columns = num_of_Columns + 1 Else: Exit For
    Debug.Print num_of_Columns


  Next

End Sub`
```