# Find Page Breaks in excel w/o Print Area

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder if there is a better solution for finding the possible location (row number) of PageBreak in the Excel sheet. Page break occurs if Print Area crosses over possible PageBreak, if not, you can't know what is the possible location of Page Break. at the moment I'm looping true cells and set Print Area for each cell and looking if there is a Page Break (code below). If you activate xlPageLayoutView Excel has information on what row Page Break occurs, pages are visually separated, but I don't know how to get that info.

```
Dim PBcountSTART As Integer: PBcountSTART = Sheets("sheet2").HPageBreaks.Count
Dim PBcountEND, LastPrintRowWithoutPB As Integer
Dim rng: Set rng = Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange
LastPrintRowWithoutPB = rng(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row

Do Until PBcountSTART = PBcountEND - 1
    LastPrintRowWithoutPB = LastPrintRowWithoutPB + 1
    Sheets("sheet2").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:" & "L" & LastPrintRowWithoutPB
    PBcountEND = Sheets("sheet2").HPageBreaks.Count
Loop
```

Comment: [How to identify page breaks in excel with VBA, varying conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46141388)

Comment: I saw that link but didn't get the answer to my question. I think my question is more precise.